# Custom WPF context menu with text on top

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I created a custom context menu template which looks like this:

[image: custom context menu]

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource menuBorderBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource menuForegroundBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="13"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
                        <Border x:Name="Border" Background="{StaticResource menuBackgroundBrush}" BorderThickness="5" BorderBrush="{StaticResource menuBackgroundBrush}">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" Padding="5,5,5,10">
                                    You are not logged in.
                                </TextBlock>
                                <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Now i'd like to be able to change the "You are not logged in." text programmatically. I tried to start by creating a custom control class which inherits from ContextMenu and change the x:Type in the XAML to this class but then the Properties (like Background, Foreground, ...) are unknown.

How can i do this without implementing a new ContextMenu from scratch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add to the `TextBlock` `Binding` with `TemplatedParent` for this.

```
<TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" Padding="5,5,5,10"
           Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Path=Tag}" />
```

And add the text to the `ContextMenu` `Tag` property, like that.

```
<Grid.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu Tag="Test menuItem text" />
</Grid.ContextMenu>
```

**Update**

There are some tricks to pass many properties. For example you can bind `ContextMenu` to viewModel with many properties. The view Model should have realization `INotifyPropertyChanged` behaviour. So you can write something like this, but with many properties.

```
public class OwnObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _text;

    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set { _text = value; NotifyPropertyChanged( "Text" ); }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    #endregion
    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged( String info )
    {
        if ( PropertyChanged != null )
        {
            PropertyChanged( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( info ) );
        }
    }
}
```

And pass this viewModel object through the `Tag` property.

```
<Grid.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu Tag="{Binding Object}" />
</Grid.ContextMenu>
```

And use it in the menu `Style` through the `Tag.Text`.

```
<TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" Padding="5,5,5,10"
     Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Path=Tag.Text}" />
```

Comment: This works, but only for one property. (Since we're using the already defined "Tag" property) Is there also a solution for an arbitrary number of properties?

Comment: Yes it's possible, I've updated the answer. Also if you want you can pass `ObservableCollection` through the `Tag` property.

Comment: Working fine, thanks! `IsIdChanged = true;` doesn't serve any purpose as far as i can tell?

Comment: Yes it doesn't. It's from other code sample, I deleted this one to avoid misunderstanding.